# How to put 2 mysqli_fetch_assoc in a single while loop in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to combine data from 2 different queries (The data are coming from 2 databases). So I put 2 `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with `&&` condition. But it didn't work. However, it works for individual `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. How to solve this or is there any different way? 
A sample code is shown here:

```
<?php
    $dalText = new DALText;
    $resultTextEnglish =  $dalText->getTextEnglish($ParaID);
    $resultTextArabic =  $dalText->getTextArabic($ParaID);

    $data = "";
    while ($resTextEnglish = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTextEnglish) && $resTextArabic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTextArabic))
    {
        $data .= '<div class="mdl-cell-a mdl-cell--12-col">';
        $data .= '['.$resTextArabic['ID'].'] ';
        $data .= $resTextArabic['Text'];
        $data .= '</div>';


        $data .= '<div class="mdl-cell-b mdl-cell--12-col">';
        $data .= '['.$resTextEnglish['ID'].'] ';
        $data .= $resTextEnglish['Text'];
        $data .= '</div>
    }
    print($data)
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you join the 2 queries ? Can you post the queries ?

Comment: Why don't you loop through them separately then join them use implode to concatenate the values?

Comment: @Vidal, No. the data are coming from 2 different sources.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by 2 different sources but Vidal is on the right track. Please edit your question and include the actual queries.

Comment: @Enoch, Will it be a good idea for huge data? There are 6,000 lines of texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible when both table has same row. If two table has different number of rows then it is false but doesn't show any error.

Like this it works fine for me.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stack_over_flow");
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error;
}
$res1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM abc");
$res2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM xyz");

while(($row1 = $res1->fetch_assoc()) && ($row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc())){
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row1['a'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row1['b'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row1['c'].'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>'.$row2['val'].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';   
}
```

Comment: I just signed in specifically to say Thank you!:)
I was searching for a solution about this dilemma for almost 3 hours. It worked!!

Comment: It's my pleasure when someone benefits from my solution.